# Why my variable hasn't its initialized value?

Tags: javascript

I initialize my constant `index` variable (inside of `case` code block) by expression that returns `2`. But I see `index` value is `undefined`... How it possible?

I created this project through `create-react-app` command and clear all JS and CSS files in the `src` subdirectory.

I published code sources of my example here: https://github.com/Andrey-Bushman/i-learn-redux (You can run the project by `npm start` or `yarn start` command).

[image]

Console output:

[image]

The `findIndex` is native function:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Chrome DevTools. `index` does have the value `2` - you will notice this if you `console.log(index)`. It looks like Chrome DevTools has a problem with the `index` variable being defined twice in this function.
If you rename one occurrence, Chrome DevTools displays the correct value.

Also, in `Local` you will see another variable `_index` which has the correct value.